# How do I add an identifier to an unwind segue - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

```
 @IBAction func unwindOtherVw (seque: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        println("the objectfromOtherView is \(objectFromOtherView!)")
    }
```

I'm passing an object (NSManaged) from the other ViewController using `prepareForSeque` method and exit in the storyboard along with the code above in the destination controller. All is working fine, but how can I add an identifier to the unwind segue so that `prepareForSegue` could use if `seque.indentifier == ______`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to see the unwind segue in the tree view of components on the left. YOU can select it and add an identifier in the attributes inspector.

eg:

[image]

Comment: That was too easy. Thx